# Can no longer pair with bluetooth keyboard

Tags: bluetooth

I am re-writing this question with more debugging info because it's driving me crazy. I cannot pair with my Lenovo Thinkpad Trackpoint II keyboard anymore after removing it from the list of devices in `gnome-control-center` once. It asks me to enter the key PIN then press enter. I do it, and nothing happens. The keyboard blinks 5 times which means it's supposed to be paired. I have no soft or hard blocks for bluetooth in my `rfkill list`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Wireless is currently soft-blocked because I turned off Wi-Fi after reading that it may help.

Nothing has worked. Here is the current buffer for `systemctl status bluetooth`:

```
Sep 02 11:33:00 anonpc bluetoothd[880]: src/profile.c:ext_start_servers() L2CAP server failed for Message Notification: setsockopt(L2CAP_OPTIONS): Invalid argument (22)
Sep 02 11:33:00 anonpc bluetoothd[880]: src/profile.c:ext_start_servers() L2CAP server failed for Message Access: setsockopt(L2CAP_OPTIONS): Invalid argument (22)
Sep 02 11:33:00 anonpc bluetoothd[880]: src/profile.c:ext_start_servers() L2CAP server failed for Phone Book Access: setsockopt(L2CAP_OPTIONS): Invalid argument (22)
Sep 02 11:33:00 anonpc bluetoothd[880]: src/profile.c:ext_start_servers() L2CAP server failed for File Transfer: setsockopt(L2CAP_OPTIONS): Invalid argument (22)
Sep 02 11:33:00 anonpc bluetoothd[880]: src/profile.c:ext_start_servers() L2CAP server failed for Object Push: setsockopt(L2CAP_OPTIONS): Invalid argument (22)
Sep 02 11:33:02 anonpc bluetoothd[880]: src/device.c:load_gatt_db() No cache for D4:E8:60:34:B6:7B
Sep 02 11:35:35 anonpc bluetoothd[880]: src/device.c:load_gatt_db() No cache for D4:E8:60:34:B6:7B
Sep 02 11:35:46 anonpc bluetoothd[880]: profiles/input/hog-lib.c:output_written_cb() Write output report failed: Request attribute has encountered an unlikely error
Sep 02 11:35:46 anonpc bluetoothd[880]: profiles/input/hog-lib.c:output_written_cb() Write output report failed: Request attribute has encountered an unlikely error
Sep 02 11:35:46 anonpc bluetoothd[880]: profiles/input/hog-lib.c:output_written_cb() Write output report failed: Request attribute has encountered an unlikely error
```

Here is the output of `sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`:

```
[    3.918616] usb 1-12: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[    5.754036] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.754064] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    5.754065] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.754070] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.754072] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.754076] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.911921] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8821
[    5.914934] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[    5.914938] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_fw.bin
[    5.915596] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_config.bin
[    5.915724] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 10, total sz 34926
[    7.073100] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x75b8f098
[    7.568173] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.568175] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.568178] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    7.574580] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[   11.039796] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   11.039805] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   11.039811] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   46.039894] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc19
[   46.040935] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x2016
[   52.036805] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected cc 0x0c7c length: 1 < 3
[   52.051280] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x06 from d4:e8:60:34:b6:7b
[   52.068280] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x07 from d4:e8:60:34:b6:7b
[   52.068287] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x08 from d4:e8:60:34:b6:7b
[   52.068289] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x09 from d4:e8:60:34:b6:7b
[   53.986986] lenovo 0005:17EF:60E1.0007: input,hidraw6: BLUETOOTH HID v0.47 Keyboard [TrackPoint Keyboard II] on 38:d5:7a:08:e9:62
[  198.586189] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc19
[  198.587192] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x2016
[  204.557040] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected cc 0x0c7c length: 1 < 3
[  204.571299] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x06 from d4:e8:60:34:b6:7b
[  204.603297] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x07 from d4:e8:60:34:b6:7b
[  204.603307] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x08 from d4:e8:60:34:b6:7b
[  204.603309] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x09 from d4:e8:60:34:b6:7b
[  206.461989] lenovo 0005:17EF:60E1.0008: input,hidraw6: BLUETOOTH HID v0.47 Keyboard [TrackPoint Keyboard II] on 38:d5:7a:08:e9:62
```

As you can see, the MAC address of my keyboard is `d4:e8:60:34:b6:7b`. My PC is also named `anonpc`. When I run `gnome-control-center -v`, I often get this message:

`Bluetooth:    DEBUG: Not interested in device 'anonpc'`

Is there something in the firmware preventing me from pairing again? I would like to factory reset the keyboard incase it's something in the firmware, but there doesn't appear to be a way to

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64 / GNOME 42.9 / 6.2.0-1011-lowlatency kernel